# node.js class - how do I get independant socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have defined a class as a node.js module. The whole class works, but the problem is, all instances of the class using the same socket id. Is there a possibility to get a independant id for each instance? Here is my node module with the class (file index.js) reduced to the first connect:

```
class TestClass {
    constructor(data, ip, port) {
        this.data = data;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.socket = null;
    }

    socketIo(){
        const ios = require("socket.io-client");
        let data = this.data;

        let serverIP = "http://" + this.ip + ":" + this.port;
        let socket = ios(serverIP, {secure: false, reconnect: true});

        socket.on("connect", async function(){
            socket.emit('channel1', data);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = TestClass
```

in my server file I do following:

```
let TestClass = require('test-class');

let tc1 = new TestClass(data, ip, port);
tc1.socketIo();  // socket id: o0OZopHi_XGh7Jm9AAAD


let tc2 = new TestClass(data, ip, port);
tc2.socketIo();  // here same socket id: o0OZopHi_XGh7Jm9AAAD
```

Both connections getting the same id from the server. Is there a way to have a unique id for each instance?

Thanks for any help!
Harald

Comment: client id is totally depends on server. check the server id generating logic.

Comment: that´s true, the server is the manager of the ids. But is there a way, that the server interprets the connection as new connection. So that it gets an separate id?